# NodeJS data throughput

Tags: node.js, http

I've set up a NodeJS server which can be accessed by a client. Every once in a while it's necessary to let the server connect to a second server and feed the information retrieved back to the client.

Connecting to the second server is the easy part, but to be honest I have no idea how to send it back to the client. `res.write` seems to be forbidden during the connection with the second server.

The connection from the client is handled by `handleGetRequest`. The connection with the second server starts at `http.get`.

```
var http = require('http');
var url  = require('url');

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  var url_parsed = url.parse(req.url, true);

  if (req.method ==='GET') {
    handleGetRequest(res, url_parsed);
  } else {
    res.end('Method not supported');
  }
});


handleGetRequest = function(res, url_parsed) {
  if (url_parsed.path == '/secondary') {
    var OPTIONS = {
      hostname: "localhost",
      port: "8900",
      path: "/from_primary"
    }

    http.get(OPTIONS, function(secget) {
      resget.on('data', function(chunk) {

      // either store 'chunk' for later use or send directly

      });
    }).on('error', function(e) {
      console.log("Error " + e.message);
    });

  } else {
    res.writeHead(404);
  }
  res.end('Closed');
};
server.listen(8000);
```

How do I send the `chunk` from `http.request` to the client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thinks passing the `callback` to the `handleGetRequest` will fix this issue:

```
if (req.method === 'GET') {
  handleGetRequest(url_parsed, function (err, response) {
    if (err) {
      return res.sendStatus(500);
    }

    res.json(response);
  });
} else {
  res.end('Method not supported');
}

handleGetRequest = function (url_parsed, callback) {
  // OPTIONS ...

  http.get(OPTIONS, function(resget) {
    var data = '';

    resget.on('data', function(chunk) {
      data += chunk;
    });

    resget.on('end', function() {
      callback(null, data);
    });
  }).on('error', function(e) {
    callback(e);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @TalgatMedetbekov for the suggestions. I managed to implement it like this:

```
var http = require('http');
var url  = require('url');

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  var url_parsed = url.parse(req.url, true);

  if (req.method ==='GET') {
    handleGetRequest(res, url_parsed);
  } else {
    res.end('Method not supported');
  }
});

handleGetSecondaryRequest = function(callback, res) {
    var OPTIONS = {
        hostname: "localhost",
        port: "8900",
        path: "/from_primary"
    }

    var data = null;

    http.get(OPTIONS, function(func, data) {
        func.on('data', function(chunk) {
          data += chunk;
        });
        func.on('end', function() {
            callback(res, data);
        });
    }).on('error', function(e) {
        callback(res, e);
    })
};

var secReqCallback = function(res, recData)
{
    res.write(recData);
    res.end("END");
};

handleGetRequest = function(res, url_parsed) {
  if (url_parsed.path == '/secondary') {
    handleGetSecondaryRequest(secReqCallback, res);

  } else {
    res.writeHead(404);
  }
};
server.listen(8000);
```

It works, kind of. There's an 'undefined' in front of the string which I can't find the cause for, but the basic functionality works perfect.

The callback construction is necessary to synchronize the asynchronous nature of NodeJS.